# Image Rotation: How to take the inverse of a non square matrix?

Tags: python, opencv

I am cutting out an image of an animal, aligning it, modifying it, then I want to paste it back into the original image. So the workflow is like this:

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Animal detected:
[image: Animal detected]

Animal aligned:
[image: Animal aligned]

Animal extracted:
[image: Animal extracted]

Modified Animal:
[image: Modified Animal]

Repasted Animal:
[image: Repasted Animal]

I have the code to detect and align the animal:

```
# get rotation matrix
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(eyesCenter, angle, scale)
# update the translation component of the matrix
tX = w * 0.5
tY = h * LeftEye[1]
M[0, 2] += (tX - eyesCenter[0])
M[1, 2] += (tY - eyesCenter[1])
# apply the affine transformation
output = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

I tried to use

```
Mp = np.linalg.inv(M)
```

But I get the error:

```
Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

How can I place the owl back into original image?

Answer (score 2):

Add a third row of [0, 0, 1]. This has the effect of making the product `y = A x` a 2d homogeneous vector (i.e. one with three components) whose first two components are the same as if you had not added the row.

Comment: I need to do this for any arbitrary image though. The rectangles could be different sizes.

Comment: @ChrisWalters But the rotation matrix is always the same size regardless of image size.

Comment: Do you have sample code?